# Help- Visa Information

Tags: visas, uk

Hi when travelling abroad do I need a visa to enter Britain?
What is an Article 10 residence card? 
Is this the same as a green card?

The problem occured while making a booking online.
I was told I only need a Green card. And there is no problem if passports Bolivian.
At the Airport I got declined.
Very difficult to use gov.uk.
Thanks.Wendy

Comment: Who told you you only need a green card?  A green card is sufficient to leave and enter the US, but it has no direct impact on your ability to enter the UK.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you hold Bolivian citizenship and are not a family member of an EEA National who is travelling with you, yes, you need a visa to enter the UK. https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/bolivia/tourism/no

An Article 10 residence card is not the same as a green card. It is a document which is issued under European Union law (‘the Free Movement Directive’) by European Economic Area Member States to non-EEA family members of EEA nationals who are exercising free movement rights in another Member State than that of their nationality. For example, the non-EEA spouse of a French national who is living and working in Italy may be issued with an Article 10 residence card by the Italian authorities. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card